# What data type should be used for inserting contact numbers into the mysql?

Tags: html, forms

I need to insert the contact number with a prefix of country code which will be more than 10 digits. The Bigint and Varchar data types are not inserting the data into the database. The HTML code for contact number is,

```
   <div class="form-group">
            <Label for="Contact Number" style="color: brown; font-size: 15px;margin-left: 10px;">Contact Number</Label><input type="number"  style="color: black;margin-left: 10px" class="form-control" id="contactnum" name="contactnum" required="required">
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use varchar in db(best for contact number).

Use `<input type="text"/>` in HTML.

Hope this could help